# isset and $_GET confusion

Tags: php

I've created a private messaging system but I have an annoying problem with $_GET.

First of all here's the full code for the "sendmail.php" page which is used for the form to send the mail

```
<?php
include("header.php");
include("connect.php");

$mailid = $_GET['username'];
$replyname = $_GET['user'];

?>

<form action="send.php" method="post" name="sendpm">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
     <font color='orange'>To</font>
  </td>
  <?php IF ($mailid != ''){ ?>
  <td>
     <input type="text" name="touser" id="touser" value="<?php echo $mailid;?>"/>
  </td>
  <?php }elseif($replyname != ''){ ?>
  <td>
     <input type="text" name="touser" id="touser" value="<?php echo $replyname;?>"/>
  </td>
  <?php }else{ ?>
  <td>
     <input type="text" name="touser" id="touser" value="<?php echo $replyname;?>"/>
  </td>
  <?php } ?>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <font color='orange'>Subject</font>
  </td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" />
  </td>
</tr>   
<tr>
  <td>
     <font color='orange'>Message</font>
  </td>
  <td>
     <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="10" id="message"></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
     <input type="submit" value="Send PM" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
```

Okay so as you can see here

```
$mailid = $_GET['username'];
$replyname = $_GET['user'];
```

I can get two different results depending on where it comes from. The "mailid" is if you've been directed from a profile. The "replyname" is if you've clicked "reply" to a message you've received.

Now, if I try to send a mail from scratch, I will be told that "username" and "user" are undefined (as I haven't come from the links that include them). If I come from one link then the other will be undefined and vice versa.

I can 'solve' this by adding `isset` but for some reason, that keeps displaying a "1" instead of the username that should be shown (and IS shown if I follow a link without isset).

This is very annoying and I've been trying to solve it for ages!

I just realised isset deals in true or false. So the "1" means it's true, so I've changed it to

```
IF(isset($_GET['username'])){
$mailid = $_GET['username'];
}

IF(isset($_GET['user'])){
$replyname = $_GET['user'];
}
```

I thought this would be fine but still shows 1?

Comment: Where are you echoing them?

Comment: just because you don't know how to use a function doesn't mean it doesn't work properly

Comment: @LoganMurphy Any need for that? A function will obviously always work correctly.

Comment: well the question suggests that there is a bug in php itself not your code...or at least it did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i would like to see how you are using isset. If you are trying something like this

```
$mailid = isset($_GET['username']);
$replyname = isset($_GET['user']);
```

Then it will return boolean.

Try this.

```
<?php
include("header.php");
include("connect.php");
?>
<form action="send.php" method="post" name="sendpm">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
     <font color='orange'>To</font>
  </td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" name="touser" id="touser" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['username'])?$_GET['username']:$_GET['user']; ?>"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <font color='orange'>Subject</font>
  </td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" />
  </td>
</tr>   
<tr>
  <td>
     <font color='orange'>Message</font>
  </td>
  <td>
     <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="10" id="message"></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
     <input type="submit" value="Send PM" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and dont forgot to filter your input.

Comment: See my "answer", I use isset to see if it's there. If you can help more check this out as everyone ignored it lol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314895/weird-if-insert-statements-not-working?noredirect=1#comment43089737_27314895

Comment: Yes you are correct. Isset returns boolean and not the value. Only one advice use ternary operator (?:) this is much quick then "if else". Moreover you can short your code with this as i did above.

Comment: Thank you, I use so many ifs and elses, that will help loads :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$mailid = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : false;
$replyname = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : false;
```

`isset` returns `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it works if you also check for !empty($var) or try using [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

```
$mailid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'username');
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself (spent 2 hours and couldn't work it out, post here and see it straight away..lol)

```
IF(isset($_GET['username'])){
$mailid = $_GET['username'];
}

IF(isset($_GET['user'])){
$replyname = $_GET['user'];
}
```

This is because isset only checks to see if it's true or not.

So it basically says "IF username is true, variable becomes username"

Answer (score 0):

I see no `isset` in your code, so it's not clear how you use it.

Usually you do like this (I prefer `empty` over `isset`):

```
$mailIdOrName = "";

if (!empty($_GET['username'])) {
    $mailIdOrName = $_GET['username'];
} elseif (!empty($_GET['user'])) {
    $mailIdOrName = $_GET['user'];
}

/* Later you will not need if-elseif-else */

<input type="text" name="touser" id="touser" value="<?php echo $mailIdOrName;?>"/>
```